# trying to get a variable from one page to repopulate it on another

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im using a dropdown box on page one that should pass the vairable to the linked page and on the second use that variable"$id" on the second in mysql query.

first page code to select who to look up

Customer Lookup

```
                        require ('dbconnect.php');
                        $result = $con->query("select id, lastname, firstname from customer");

                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        unset($id, $name);
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $name = $row['lastname'];
                        $firstname = $row['firstname']; 

                        echo '<option value="/customerpage.php?='.$id.'">'.$name.','.$firstname.'</option>';

                        }

                        echo "</select>";
                        mysqli_close($con);
                        ?>
```

Second page which is the receiving page

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;


require ('dbconnect.php');

                            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                            }
                                 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id='$id'");
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                              echo $row['firstname'];

                              echo "<br>";
                                    }

?>
```

the second page url comes up great with /customerpage.php?=1

Comment: Look at your first code... "<option value="/customerpage.php?='.$id.'">" - of course it's going to come up with ?=1, you told it to.

Comment: Why are you having `value="/customerpage.php?` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=' . $id . '");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing id from select box to another php page. You should use `id` as key in query string.

```
echo '<option value="/customerpage.php?id='.$id.'">'.$name.','.$firstname.'</option>';
```

Now, in your second file you are getting it from `$_GET`

Your query will be -

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=$id");
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first page in the option your omitted the key 'id'

```
 echo '<option value="/customerpage.php?id='.$id.'">'.$name.','.$firstname.'</option>';
```